# Querying JSON API with node.js

Tags: json, api, node.js

How should querying a JSON API be done best in node.js? Is there a module that will simplify this?

I am trying to get the City location from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452

I would use jQuery to query the API in client-side because it vastly simplifies things. Is there something similar for node.js?

Comment: What's wrong with a GET `http.request` to the URL?

Comment: @Raynos: it's too low level. You need to combine data chunks, to begin with. No automatic redirect following etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The `request` module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) makes http-request very easy. Just place a GET request to your URL and `JSON.parse()` the response. You might want to use `encodeURIComponent()` for your query parameters.